# Android: Manage fragments in chain from activity

Tags: android, android-fragments

I'm very new to android development and want to create an ACTIVITY, which will have placeholder for fragment and one button. Buttono click will replace the fragment with next fragment.

I want to know what will be better design to solve below mentioned requirement:

I'm creating fragments dynamically and want these fragments to be independent of others, which puts whole responsibility to manage the fragments flow over activity. Easy solution will be creating map with position and instance of fragments but then have to track position variable very correctly otherwise things won't work. I want to know if there is any better solution like saving chain of fragments in order and at run time find out, which fragment is user using when he clicked button.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a View pager with a FragmentPagerAdapter. In click of button just navigate to the next page of the view pager.

This way you can have any number of fragments you want to have and it will be loaded on demand basis.

You will have an added feature of swipe for navigation to next / previous fragment. If you want you can opt out.

Comment: Looks nice option to try. I will try and let you know if things works as I expected.